# Remove all the blocks from left sidebar

Tags: layout-update, sidebar

Consider i have three blocks on left sidebar namely `block_1`, `block_2` and `block_3`

i can remove all of the above block by using below code

```
<remove name="block_1" />
<remove name="block_2" />
<remove name="block_3" />
```

but i dont want to use above code as blocks in my sidebar are coming dynamically. so i am looking for code which will remove all the block, something like `<remove name="all" />`

Comment: try `<remove name="left">`

Comment: Have you tried the solutions below? Do they work for you? Then please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Via layout XML (although this will remove the whole block including the container):

```
<remove name="left" />
```

Programmatically: In your `config.xml`, listen to the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` (this will keep the container, but will remove all child blocks):

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    <observers>
        <your_extension>
            <class>your_extension/observer</class>
            <method>coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore</method>
        </your_extension>
    </observers>
<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

And then in your `Observer.php`, unset all children if the current block is the block of the left sidebar:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    /* @var Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block */
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block->getNameInLayout() == 'left') {
        $block->unsetChildren();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could try removing block `left` and creating it again. I haven't tried it myself but similar approaches are known to be used elsewhere.